# python array size error only occurs in binary release but not when running from source

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller, release

I have a python [app](https://github.com/malonzo47/pynita_GUI) that can be run from downloaded binary release or from source. When I run the .exe file, I get the following error from trying to load a very large image stack:

`array is too big; arr.size * arr.dtype.itemsize is larger than the maximum possible size`

However, when I run this code from source (from CMD or from Spyder) I do NOT get this error. So I'm guessing this is something with how the developer (sadly, not me) packaged the code or set requirements?

Can I get some thoughts about what to look for since I don't *think* the issue is in the main code.

Comment: How large?  If it is multiple gigabytes, it's possible the original packager made a 32-bit exe.  When you run it from a command-line, you're probably running a 64-bit Python.

Comment: 1.5 GB (I have 64 GB RAM). I'd agree that this is possible. In what kind of file would one look to confirm this?

Comment: This is line in the .exe.manifest file. Not sure if this is useful `<assemblyIdentity name="pynita_gui_main_win" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>`

Comment: That would be a 64-bit app.  Confusing.  You should be able to create a 1.5GB numpy array.